# fullcalendar adding event entry after 10 pm shows in same day and also replicates in next day

Tags: fullcalendar

if i try to add the event entry for after 10pm, its replicates in another day also.

```
ex: Adding entry for 2015-08-10T22:15:00(Monday), it replicates in another day(Tuesday) at 12am also.

$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'agendaWeek'
            },
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            defaultDate: '2015-08-10',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: [
                {
                    title: 'All Day Event',
                    start: '2015-08-10T21:00:00'
                },
                {
                    id: 999,
                    title: 'Repeating Event',
                    start: '2015-08-10T23:15:00'
                }
            ]
        });

    });
```

Comment: can you update the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/man_luck/ty6vgbuf/ to show how you are doing it. I have tried to update the start date of the first array value asigned to events property but it is not duplicating it in another day

Comment: i think full calendar is not fully functional in jsfiddle. please check the demo file in this link http://162.144.41.156/~izaapinn/fullcalendar/cal/demos/agenda-views.html

Comment: I cant edit it. But the reason is that the event is showing the correct duration and hence stretching beyond 12 am on Tuesday. For example if the event is for 2 hours duration and you set the start time as 22:15 pm on Monday, the end time would be 00:15 on Tuesday (which is 12:15 am on Tuesday). I can't edit a thing but can drag and reschedule it for Monday.

Comment: I have moved it to start at 10:45 and end at 11:45 and its not duplicating over to Tuesday

Comment: how do i reduce default event duration? i want both start and end should be same time. now i have update the code with end time. (start and end are same time). Still I'm facing same issue.

Comment: @man_luck if i set end date greater than start date (at least 1sec) its not duplicates in next day. if i set both start and end date with same time, its stretching the event with 2hours duration.

Comment: this is beyond the original question. You use defaultEventMinutes property while initializing the tinyMCE object; http://fullcalendar.io/docs1/agenda/defaultEventMinutes/

Comment: As I said I cannot edit the calendar. can you share your html and js code? I have used fullcalendar with no problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant edit it. But the reason is that the event is showing the correct duration and hence stretching beyond 12 am on Tuesday. For example if the event is for 2 hours duration and you set the start time as 22:15 pm on Monday, the end time would be 00:15 on Tuesday (which is 12:15 am on Tuesday). I can't edit a thing but can drag and reschedule it for Monday.

I have moved it to start at 10:45 and end at 11:45 and its not duplicating over to Tuesday

[image]